# Multiple Insert, Update and Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having three tables

Present , History and Hold Table

By the end of the day I have to clear the entire present table data like
 If there is an Id with the existing one in History table then I have to look at the balance  and then subtract current balance from that table.

If balance- currentbalance < 0  then subtract the balance from history table make it zero and add a new row in history table with currentbalance-balance as balance

If there is no ID in history table and currentbalance > 0 move that record to hold table .

If currentbalance < = 0 change the date in the present table to next day. I just need a single query for all this.

If there is a record in hold table remove that record and place the latest record.

Every time when u update a row change the DATE column to current date apart from present table.

Present:

```
ID      Current_Balance    Date
 1        2000              25-06-2014
 2        1500              25-06-2014
 3        5000              25-06-2014
 2        6000              25-06-2014
 4        -200              25-06-2014
```

History:

```
 ID       Balance           Date
 1        1500             24-06-2014
 2        1600             24-06-2014
```

Hold Table:

```
 ID       Balance           Date
 3         125             24-06-2014
 4         2000            24-06-2014
```

I want result like 
 Present:

```
 ID      Current_Balance     Date
 4       -200                26-06-2014
```

History:

```
 Id    Balance              Date
 1     0                    25-06-2014
 1     500                  25-06-2014
 2     100                  25-06-2014
```

Hold:

```
 ID      Balance            Date
 3        5000              25-06-2014
 4        2000              24-06-2014
```

I have written my code which is a bit complex. Can anyone give me optimum solution for this.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Best way to write this code. In the sense how effective i can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following query:

```
UPDATE Persent
SET current_Balance = 0,
    Date = GETDATE()
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Deleted.current_Balance, Deleted.Date
INTO #P
FROM History h
WHERE h.Id = Persent.ID
    AND  h.balance - Persent.current_balance < 0


INSERT INTO History (Id, Balance, Date)
SELECT p.Id, p.Current_Balance, p.Date
FROM #P p

MERGE Hold AS Destination
 USING (SELECT * FROM Present WHERE Current_Balance>0) AS Source ON Destination.Id = Source.Id
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, Balance, Date) VALUES (ID,Current_Balance,Date)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE


UPDATE Persent
SET Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
WHERE Persent.current_balance <= 0
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried the same kind of but not exactly the same....